# If $ T \circ T = -Id_v$ then $T$ has no eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $V$ be a vector space above $\mathbb R$. and let $T:V\rightarrow
>  V$ linear operator with $ T \circ  T = -Id_v$. Prove that $T$ doesn't have any eigenvectors.

I thought about finding the eigenvalues of $T$ and see that they don't exist, and by that showing that there are no eigenvectors, is this a good approach? and if yes, how do I exactly find the eigenvalues? because I don't have enough information to get the matrix reperesntation of this operator (Or do I have?).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question should be "prove that $T$ has no eigenvectors with real coordinates". Here is a proof by contradiction.

If $v \in V$ is an eigenvector associated with $\lambda$, i.e., $Tv=\lambda v$, then

$$T^2v=T(Tv)=T(\lambda v)=\lambda Tv=\lambda^2 v.$$

Thus, taking into account $T^2v=-v$, we conclude that, necessarily, $\lambda = \pm i.$

But it is impossible to have $Tv=\pm i v$ with real components for $v$.

The reason is that, on the LHS, one would have real values whereas on the RHS, one would have pure imaginary values.